# Javascript(jQuery) hiding and appearing css files like a menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement, menu

I am trying to make a menu with display:none and display:block. To be honest I'm not sure whats the best way to do this. They have to be images because they are a different font I'm using in photoshop. This is my HTML.

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div>
        <img class="difficulty-rally"src="assets/images/difficulty-rally.png">
        <div class="difficulties">
            <img class="difficulty-easy"src="assets/images/easy-green.png">
            <img class="difficulty-medium"src="assets/images/medium-green.png">
            <img class="difficulty-hard"src="assets/images/hard-green.png">
            <img class="difficulty-insane"src="assets/images/insane-green.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS

```
@import 'reset.css';
/*///////////////////MAIN/////////////////////////*/
#wrap{
    height: 500px;
    width:  800px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: -900000;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#main{
    position: relative;
}
#header{
    height: 52px;
    width: 295px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.title{
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 52px;
    width: 295px;
    background-image: url(../images/title.png);
}
.difficulty-rally{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1000;
}
.diificulties{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;
    height: 230px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-top: 157px;
    margin-left: 335px;
}
.difficulty-easy{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 30;
    display: none;
}
.difficulty-medium{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 30;
    top: 62px;
    left: 2px;
    display: block;
}
.difficulty-hard{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 30;
    bottom: 62px;
    left: 3px;
    display: none;
}
.difficulty-insane{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 30;
    bottom: 1px;
    left: 2px;
    display: none;
}
```

This is my JavaScript(jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('keyup', function(e){
        if(e.keyCode === 27){
            window.location = 'minigame.php';
        }   
    })

    var easy = $('.difficulty-easy');
    var medium = $('.difficulty-medium');
    var hard = $('.difficulty-hard');
    var insane = $('.difficulty-insane');

    $(document).on('keyup', function(e){
        if(e.keyCode === 40 && medium.css('display') == "block"){
            medium.css({'display' : 'none'});
            hard.css({'display' : 'block'})
        }
        if(e.keyCode === 38 && medium.css('display') == "block"){
            medium.css({'display' : 'none'});
            easy.css({'display' : 'block'})
        }
        if(e.keyCode === 40 && easy.css('display') == "block"){
            easy.css({'display' : 'none'});
            medium.css({'display' : 'block'})
        }
        if(e.keyCode === 38 && easy.css('display') == "block"){
            easy.css({'display' : 'none'});
            insane.css({'display' : 'block'})
        }
    })

});
```

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to explain the problem, basically when I click up on the medium it goes to insane instead of easy!

I know that I'm not done with some of the selections, but sense they aren't working I will post here.

EDITx2:

```
easy.hide();
hard.hide();
insane.hide();
medium.show();

$(document).on('keyup', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 40 && medium.show();){
        medium.hide();
        hard.show();
    }
    if(e.keyCode === 40 && hard.show();){
        hard.hide();
        insane.show();
    }
})
```

**ANSWER:**

```
    var current = 1;
    var difficulties = $('#difficulties > img');

    $(document).on('keyup', function(e){
        if(e.keyCode === 40){
            current = current + 1;
        }
        if(e.keyCode === 38){
            current = current - 1;
        }

        var selectedIndex = current % difficulties.length; //so you can click enter and do something

        if(e.keyCode === 13){
            alert($(difficulties.get(selectedIndex)).text()) //example of what you can do
        }

        $(difficulties.get(current % difficulties.length)).show().siblings().hide();
    })

});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With JQuery, you can use `.hide()` to hide things and `.show()` to show them instead of messing with the css

change your keyup handler to:

```
var current = 1;
var difficulties = $('#difficulties > img');


$(document).on('keyup', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 40){
        current = current + 1;
    }
    if(e.keyCode === 38){
        current = current - 1;
    }

    var selectedIndex = current % difficulties.length; //so you can click enter and do something

    if(e.keyCode === 13){
        alert($(difficulties.get(selectedIndex)).text()) //example of what you can do
    }

    $(difficulties.get(current % difficulties.length)).show().siblings().hide();
})
```

Comment: Do you I put the easy.hide(); and other ones outside of the keyup handler? btw I didnt down vote(icant) idk who did.

Comment: I'm having the same problem! :( I click the up key and it jumps from medium to insane. Even though its supposed to go to easy. sorry..uhhh

Comment: I updated my answer, maybe the problem is the visible tests.  If this doesnt work, can I suggest you make a fiddle: www.jsfiddle.net, that way everyone is on the same page.

Comment: thank you sir. I found the answer, sense you gave me so much help I would give you a check mark if you change your answer to the one I edited up there^